Reorder a stacked barplot in altair
So I am making an interactive plot (which is why I'm using altair) and I want to reorder the stacks within each bar to match the legend. I've tried reodering the df, I've tried using the 'sort' parameter, but nothing works. Any suggestions would be extremely helpful!
color_scale = alt.Scale(
    domain=['Strongly disagree', 'Somewhat disagree', 'Neither agree nor disagree', 'Somewhat agree', 'Strongly agree'],
    range=['#FF0000', '#FF6347', '#A9A9A9', '#87CEEB', '#4682B4']
)

# Define the brush selection
brush = alt.selection_interval(encodings=['x'])


# Define the plot_bar chart and filter the data according to the brush selection
plot_bar = alt.Chart(new_df).mark_bar().encode(
    x='value',
    y=alt.Y("question:N", axis=alt.Axis(title='Question')),  # Use the specified y-axis title
    color=alt.Color("type:N", title="Response", scale=color_scale, sort=desired_order),  # Specify the desired order for the legend
).transform_filter(
    brush
).properties(
    width=400, height=250  # Adjust the width of the chart as needed
)

plot_bar



Please post a sample dataframe

In the docs, there is an example of how you can use order encoding to achieve this:
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.barley()

alt.Chart(source).mark_bar().encode(
    x='sum(yield)',
    y='variety',
    color='site',
    order=alt.Order(
      # Sort the segments of the bars by this field
      'site',
      sort='ascending'
    )
)

